# La consola de Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

Estoy experimentando con las consultas en Mongo DB en la terminal de mandatos. De vez en cuando, la consola deja de responder. Tecleo algo como `db.coleccion.find()` y, al pulsar **enter**, el cursor, simplemente, pasa a la siguiente línea, sin mostrar el resultado. Sé que hay documentos. Si abandono el entorno Mongo con `CTRL-C`, cierro la consola y vuelvo a abrirla, la instrucción funciona, y me muestra los documentos. ¿por qué a veces es necesario esto? ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Puede que lo que este pasando es que este esperando mas comandos. Que SO usas? Y en que terminal te esta pasando?

Comment: Hola, utilizo Windows 8, y como consola he probado con Git Bash y con Cygwin. Me pasa en las dos, así que pienso que no debe ser cosa de la consola en sí.

Comment: Prueba con CMD. Ya me he encontrado con problemas similares en algunas de esas terminales. No siempre, pero no esta de mas descartar